# Check whether an Excel file printed or not

Tags: vba, excel, abap

I am an abap programmer and print documents by using OLE to output Excel files. 
The program calls "Printpreview" method of workbook to display preview interface to users.

I want to check whether the users click "print" button or not.
If a document is printed ( print button is clicked ), program will lock related data. If users only view document in print preview, program will not lock related data.

I have looked up into MSDN, it seems the workbook object only has "[saved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saved-property-excel)" property, but not "printed" property.

Can I implement this by using ABAP or VBA?

---

The program sample is showed as below. By OLE, it opens an EXCEL file which generated by other codes, calls PrintPreview method, then close and quit.

I want to determine whether it is printed between 'Printpreview' and 'Close'.
After closing the excel object, program will do something according to whether it is printed.

---

```
CREATE OBJECT excelobj 'Excel.Application'.

* Set excel visible
SET PROPERTY OF excelobj 'Visible' = 1.

* Create workbook object
CALL METHOD OF excelobj 'Workbooks' = workbooks.

CALL METHOD OF workbooks 'Open' = wbookobj
  EXPORTING
    #1 = 'C:\SAP\ZREIGNWOOD_PO.xlsx'.

CALL METHOD OF  excelobj  'Worksheets' = wsheetobj
  EXPORTING
    #1           = 'Sheet1'.

CALL METHOD OF wsheetobj 'Activate'.

CALL METHOD OF wsheetobj 'Printpreview'.

WAIT UP TO '0.1' SECONDS.
*determine whether it is printed

CALL METHOD OF wbookobj 'Close'.

CALL METHOD OF excelobj 'Quit'.

CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_DELETE_FILE'
  EXPORTING
    file_name = 'C:\SAP\ZREIGNWOOD_PO.xlsx'.
  EXCEPTIONS
    failed    = 1
    OTHERS    = 2.
```

Comment: BeforePrint Event ? Maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-beforeprint-event-excel#     http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2009/12/23/excel-vba-show-a-message-before-printing/

Comment: In what scope do you need to have this information?  ie., does it need to be retained after the workbook is closed?

Comment: BeforePrint Event will be triggered by PrintPreview method, not only PrintOut method. And the program calls PrintPreview to prevent users from editing the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

This built-in document property should help:

```
ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item(10)
```

This property contains the **date/time that the document was last printed**, if ever.

How you should use that depends on the scope of your requirement for this information, what you intend to do with it, and other considerations such as "what are you comparing it to?" .... You're concerned about when the user prints the document.. as opposed to what?  Does it automatically print as well?

If you want to know if the document has been printed since it was opened, you could use the `Workbook_Open` event to store the Last Print Date at that point:

```
Public lastPrinted As Date

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    lastPrinted = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item(10)
End Sub
```

...and later compare `lastPrinted` to `ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item(10)` to determine whether it was printed since then.

Alternatively, you could assign a value to a variable with the `Workbook_BeforePrint`, which would even allow you to **prevent** printing depending on your criteria, if that's you're end-goal, or you could set a **custom document property** if that would help.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties` Property** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-builtindocumentproperties-property-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties` Property** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-customdocumentproperties-property-excel)

---

### Other built-in document properties

```
 1  :  Title
 2  :  Subject
 3  :  Author
 4  :  Keywords
 5  :  Comments
 6  :  Template
 7  :  Last author
 8  :  Revision number
 9  :  Application name
10  :  Last print date
11  :  Creation date
12  :  Last save time
13  :  Total editing time
14  :  Number of pages
15  :  Number of words
16  :  Number of characters
17  :  Security
18  :  Category
19  :  Format
20  :  Manager
21  :  Company
22  :  Number of bytes
23  :  Number of lines
24  :  Number of paragraphs
25  :  Number of slides
26  :  Number of notes
27  :  Number of hidden Slides
28  :  Number of multimedia clips
29  :  Hyperlink base
30  :  Number of characters (with spaces)
31  :  Content type
32  :  Content status
33  :  Language
34  :  Document version
```

---

Slightly off-topic, but while I'm at it I might as well include code that will return a list of **all** built-in and custom document properties:

```
Sub listDocumentProperties()
'lists all built-in and custom document properties for the active Office document
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim p As DocumentProperty, x As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook ' ...or ActiveDocument or ActivePresentation etc.

        'list built-in properties
        Debug.Print "Built-in Document Properties for " & .Name
        For Each p In .BuiltinDocumentProperties
            x = x + 1
            Debug.Print Format(x, "\#00\: ") & p.Name & String(35 - Len(p.Name), " "), ;
            Debug.Print p.Value
            If Err Then
                Debug.Print "<N/A>"
                Err.Clear
            End If
        Next

        'list custom properties
        Debug.Print vbLf & "Custom Document Properties for " & .Name
        x = 0
        For Each p In .CustomDocumentProperties
            x = x + 1
            Debug.Print Format(x, "\#00\: ") & p.Name & String(35 - Len(p.Name), " "), ;
            Debug.Print p.Value
            If Err Then
                Debug.Print "<N/A>"
                Err.Clear
            End If
        Next
        If x = 0 Then Debug.Print "(No Custom Properties Found)"
    End With
End Sub
```

This will work in any Office application; you'll just need to change the `With` line to the appropriate document type.

---

### Alternative Solution:

Another possible solution is to use the `Workbook_BeforePrint` event to populate a public variable.

Place this at the top of a **standard module**:

```
Option Explicit
Public lastPrinted As Date
```

...and then place this in the **`ThisWorkbook` module**:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    lastPrinted = Now()
End Sub
```

...and then you should be able to tell whether the document was actually sent to the printer (as opposed to previewed) by checking the value of `lastPrinted`.  If it was not printed (since the document was opened) it should contain zero, otherwise it will contain the date/time the document was *sent* to the printer.  Note that there's no way to tell if the printer successfully printed it.

Note that you can also prevent printing by instead using this in the **`ThisWorkbook` module**:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

If you're unsure where to place the code in the **`ThisWorkbook` module** or **Standard module**, see [this guide](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/code.htm).

Comment: I was wondering if a public boolean could be returned from before print thereby indicating if saved

Comment: oohh....that sounds interesting....how do you refresh its value though?

Comment: I guess. I am wondering do you use a script to pick up the value and the environment variable points to the script? Don't want to hijack this post though, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After reading you post, I tried property “Last print date”, and I mentioned that once called "PrintPreview" method, the propery updated. But, in fact, the document was not printed, it was only viewed in preview. So, it seems I can't determine whether a document was really printed by this “Last print date”.

Comment: @CruelMoon If you explain *why* you need to know when it was printed, that might help.  Are you trying to **prevent** it from being printed?  What exactly do mean mean about "locking related data"?  What will it do according to whether it's printed?

Comment: OK, let me try.... In our business, the document is a "Purchase Order" which generated in ERP system, all of the order data is saved in ERP system. Users can print order to paper, and do their work by this paper. To avoid data inconsistent, after printing, ERP system will lock the order. So I need to know whether the document is printed or not.